# Mathematica Manipulate[] for plotting a function of several variables

Tags: manipulate, physics

This is a sample snippet from Mathematica documentation for plotting Bessel for various n:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

How can you use Manipulate[] to animate this over both x and n (so if I wanted a slider for x and n). I've tried this:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, xmax}, 
  Filling -> Axis],
 {xmax, 0, 10 , Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

But get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `0` in  `{xmax, 0, 10 , Appearance -> "Open"}` with a small number (say, `10.^-5`) to avoid the error:

```
Manipulate[Plot[BesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, xmax}, Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-.7, .7}}], 
{xmax, 10.^-5, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}, 
{n, 1, 4, 1}]
```

[image]

Use [`TogglerBar`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TogglerBar.html) as control to select subsets of `Range[5]` to as the parameter `n`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[BesselJ[#, x] & /@ n], {x, 0, xmax}, 
  Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-.7, .7}}], 
{{xmax, 6}, 10.^-5, 10, Appearance -> "Open"},
{{n, {1, 3}}, Range[5], TogglerBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: when the function is of two varibles like this:Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[prob[y, t, #] & /@ n],
  {y, 0, 2},
  
  Filling -> Axis,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 3}}],
 {{t, 10.^-5}, 0, TIMELAPSE, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{n, {1}}, Range[10], TogglerBar}
 ] it's not working and adding new filled plots, how do you do it with two vars?